# RestSharp Deserialization with JSON Array (Null)

Tags: c#, json, list, deserialization, restsharp

I'm having challenges trying to deserialize a json array into a .NET POCO object.

Here is my generated POCO class (I used json2csharp):

```
public class ClosedBy
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class SysDomain
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class AssignmentGroup
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class CallerId
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class CmdbCi
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class OpenedBy
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string skills { get; set; }
    public string u_technical_service { get; set; }
    public string urgency { get; set; }
    public string correlation_id { get; set; }
    public string u_assigned_above_tier_1 { get; set; }
    public string u_business_service { get; set; }
    public string group_list { get; set; }
    public string follow_up { get; set; }
    public string closed_at { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public ClosedBy closed_by { get; set; }
    public string work_start { get; set; }
    public string calendar_stc { get; set; }
    public string incident_state { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string business_duration { get; set; }
    public string u_resolve_code { get; set; }
    public string correlation_display { get; set; }
    public string due_date { get; set; }
    public string u_first_level_resolvable { get; set; }
    public string knowledge { get; set; }
    public string made_sla { get; set; }
    public string comments_and_work_notes { get; set; }
    public string u_incident_dashboard { get; set; }
    public string user_input { get; set; }
    public string u_first_call_resolution { get; set; }
    public string rfc { get; set; }
    public string u_sla_due { get; set; }
    public string child_incidents { get; set; }
    public string u_first_assigned_to { get; set; }
    public string u_incident_model { get; set; }
    public string upon_reject { get; set; }
    public string u_set_to_p1 { get; set; }
    public string approval_history { get; set; }
    public string u_template { get; set; }
    public string work_notes { get; set; }
    public string u_reopened { get; set; }
    public string u_in_stock { get; set; }
    public string sys_id { get; set; }
    public string u_affected_user { get; set; }
    public string u_major_incident { get; set; }
    public string u_test_alex2 { get; set; }
    public string sys_created_by { get; set; }
    public string business_stc { get; set; }
    public string subcategory { get; set; }
    public string u_actual_start_date { get; set; }
    public string contact_type { get; set; }
    public string time_worked { get; set; }
    public string u_kb_article { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string upon_approval { get; set; }
    public string u_resolving_company { get; set; }
    public string u_old_number { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string expected_start { get; set; }
    public string reopen_count { get; set; }
    public string u_schedule { get; set; }
    public string close_notes { get; set; }
    public string u_asset_redeployable { get; set; }
    public string service_offering { get; set; }
    public string impact { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public SysDomain sys_domain { get; set; }
    public string u_on_hold_type { get; set; }
    public string sys_mod_count { get; set; }
    public string work_notes_list { get; set; }
    public string u_actual_end_date { get; set; }
    public string u_cancelled_sub_state { get; set; }
    public string sla_due { get; set; }
    public string u_priority_down { get; set; }
    public string sys_updated_on { get; set; }
    public string u_critical_outage_communicatio { get; set; }
    public string work_end { get; set; }
    public string u_protocol_not_followed { get; set; }
    public string activity_due { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string active { get; set; }
    public string u_created_by_tier_1 { get; set; }
    public string u_sub_state { get; set; }
    public AssignmentGroup assignment_group { get; set; }
    public CallerId caller_id { get; set; }
    public string parent_incident { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string approval_set { get; set; }
    public string sys_created_on { get; set; }
    public string reassignment_count { get; set; }
    public string u_lateral_assignment { get; set; }
    public string u_attached_knowledge { get; set; }
    public string u_symptom { get; set; }
    public string opened_at { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
    public string short_description { get; set; }
    public string u_incident_state_count { get; set; }
    public string resolved_by { get; set; }
    public string sys_updated_by { get; set; }
    public string notify { get; set; }
    public string u_priority_up { get; set; }
    public string problem_id { get; set; }
    public string calendar_duration { get; set; }
    public string close_code { get; set; }
    public string approval { get; set; }
    public string caused_by { get; set; }
    public string severity { get; set; }
    public string u_kb_solution_steps { get; set; }
    public string resolved_at { get; set; }
    public string assigned_to { get; set; }
    public string u_sla_met { get; set; }
    public CmdbCi cmdb_ci { get; set; }
    public OpenedBy opened_by { get; set; }
    public string sys_class_name { get; set; }
    public string u_first_line_resolved { get; set; }
    public string watch_list { get; set; }
    public string escalation { get; set; }
    public string u_device_asset_name { get; set; }
    public string u_open_url { get; set; }
}

public class RootObjectList
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the json result:

```
{"result":[{"skills":"","u_technical_service":"","urgency":"1","correlation_id":"","u_assigned_above_tier_1":"false","u_business_service":"","group_list":"","follow_up":"","closed_at":"2015-02-17 23:43:26","parent":"","number":"INC0000101","closed_by":{"link":"https://some url","value":"6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441"},"work_start":"","calendar_stc":"5283743","incident_state":"7","category":"inquiry","business_duration":"1970-01-15 14:43:26","u_resolve_code":"","correlation_display":"","due_date":"","u_first_level_resolvable":"false","knowledge":"false","made_sla":"false","comments_and_work_notes":"","u_incident_dashboard":"false","user_input":"","u_first_call_resolution":"false","rfc":"","u_sla_due":"","child_incidents":"","u_first_assigned_to":"","u_incident_model":"","upon_reject":"cancel","u_set_to_p1":"","approval_history":"","u_template":"","work_notes":"","u_reopened":"false","u_in_stock":"","sys_id":"ccefe8620a0006d400b6b6e1beec71d7","u_affected_user":"","u_major_incident":"false","u_test_alex2":"","sys_created_by":"admin","business_stc":"1262606","subcategory":"","u_actual_start_date":"","contact_type":"phone","time_worked":"","u_kb_article":"","comments":"","upon_approval":"proceed","u_resolving_company":"","u_old_number":"","location":{"link":"someurl","value":"db9a923c0a0a0a6501068d6eaec25ee0"},"expected_start":"","reopen_count":"","u_schedule":"","close_notes":"Done","u_asset_redeployable":"","service_offering":"","impact":"1","priority":"2","description":"","sys_domain":{"link":"https:someurl","value":"global"},"u_on_hold_type":"","sys_mod_count":"9","work_notes_list":"","u_actual_end_date":"","u_cancelled_sub_state":"","sla_due":"","u_priority_down":"","sys_updated_on":"2015-02-18 00:16:58","u_critical_outage_communicatio":"","work_end":"","u_protocol_not_followed":"false","activity_due":"","company":"","active":"false","u_created_by_tier_1":"false","u_sub_state":"1","assignment_group":{"link":"someurl","value":"d625dccec0a8016700a222a0f7900d06"},"caller_id":{"link":"someurl","value":"9ee1b13dc6112271007f9d0efdb69cd0"},"parent_incident":"","state":"7","approval_set":"","sys_created_on":"2014-12-18 20:02:23","reassignment_count":"0","u_lateral_assignment":"false","u_attached_knowledge":"","u_symptom":"","opened_at":"2014-12-18 20:01:03","order":"","short_description":"Bond Trading app is not available","u_incident_state_count":"","resolved_by":"","sys_updated_by":"Timothy_Woodruff","notify":"1","u_priority_up":"","problem_id":"","calendar_duration":"1970-03-03 03:42:23","close_code":"Solved (Work Around)","approval":"not requested","caused_by":"","severity":"3","u_kb_solution_steps":"","resolved_at":"","assigned_to":"","u_sla_met":"","cmdb_ci":{"link":"someurl","value":"250b0f530a0a0b1d00b60acc42ff36a6"},"opened_by":{"link":"someurl","value":"6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441"},"sys_class_name":"incident","u_first_line_resolved":"false","watch_list":"","escalation":"0","u_device_asset_name":"","u_open_url":""},{"skills":"","u_technical_service":"","urgency":"1","correlation_id":"","u_assigned_above_tier_1":"false","u_business_service":"","group_list":"","follow_up":"","closed_at":"2015-02-17 23:43:27","parent":"","number":"INC0000102","closed_by":{"link":"someurl","value":"6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441"},"work_start":"","calendar_stc":"3362","incident_state":"7","category":"inquiry","business_duration":"1970-01-01 00:56:02","u_resolve_code":"","correlation_display":"","due_date":"","u_first_level_resolvable":"false","knowledge":"false","made_sla":"true","comments_and_work_notes":"","u_incident_dashboard":"false","user_input":"","u_first_call_resolution":"false","rfc":"","u_sla_due":"","child_incidents":"","u_first_assigned_to":"","u_incident_model":"","upon_reject":"cancel","u_set_to_p1":"","approval_history":"","u_template":"","work_notes":"","u_reopened":"false","u_in_stock":"","sys_id":"cd5149720a0006d400a0bc76eccf54cc","u_affected_user":"","u_major_incident":"false","u_test_alex2":"","sys_created_by":"admin","business_stc":"3362","subcategory":"","u_actual_start_date":"","contact_type":"phone","time_worked":"","u_kb_article":"","comments":"","upon_approval":"proceed","u_resolving_company":"","u_old_number":"","location":{"link":"someurl","value":"db9a923c0a0a0a6501068d6eaec25ee0"},"expected_start":"","reopen_count":"","u_schedule":"","close_notes":"Done","u_asset_redeployable":"","service_offering":"","impact":"1","priority":"1","description":"","sys_domain":{"link":"someurl","value":"global"},"u_on_hold_type":"","sys_mod_count":"4","work_notes_list":"","u_actual_end_date":"","u_cancelled_sub_state":"","sla_due":"","u_priority_down":"","sys_updated_on":"2015-02-17 23:43:27","u_critical_outage_communicatio":"","work_end":"","u_protocol_not_followed":"false","activity_due":"2015-02-18 00:49:35","company":"","active":"false","u_created_by_tier_1":"false","u_sub_state":"","assignment_group":{"link":"someurl","value":"d625dccec0a8016700a222a0f7900d06"},"caller_id":{"link":"someurl","value":"9ee1b13dc6112271007f9d0efdb69cd0"},"parent_incident":"","state":"7","approval_set":"","sys_created_on":"2015-02-17 22:48:01","reassignment_count":"0","u_lateral_assignment":"false","u_attached_knowledge":"","u_symptom":"","opened_at":"2015-02-17 22:47:25","order":"","short_description":"App is not visible","u_incident_state_count":"","resolved_by":"","sys_updated_by":"admin","notify":"1","u_priority_up":"","problem_id":"","calendar_duration":"1970-01-01 00:56:02","close_code":"Solved (Work Around)","approval":"not requested","caused_by":"","severity":"3","u_kb_solution_steps":"","resolved_at":"","assigned_to":"","u_sla_met":"","cmdb_ci":{"link":"https://somerul","value":"250b0f530a0a0b1d00b60acc42ff36a6"},"opened_by":{"link":"someurl","value":"6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441"},"sys_class_name":"incident","u_first_line_resolved":"false","watch_list":"","escalation":"0","u_device_asset_name":"","u_open_url":""}]}
```

Here is how I'm calling RestSharp:

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/now/table/incident", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

var response = client.Execute<RootObjectList>(request);

if (response.Data == null)
   throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage);
```

The ErrorMessage I get is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

I've also tried reading several other stackoverflow postings as well with no success on my end. If anyone could help out, it would be so much appreciated!  :)  Have a great day!

Comment: That is one huge JSON. You should make an effort to minimize it to the part which is causing the error

Comment: I can successfully deserialize the JSON string in your question with `SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<RootObjectList>(json)`.  This suggests the response you are receiving isn't what you think; perhaps it's some sort text message?

Comment: Thank you Yuval. Yes, this is only a snippet of the JSON that is actually returned. I think the first agenda at hand is for me to find the offending Result objectin the List that is causing this error however this is difficult because the result count is in the thousands of Result object. I also tried this line of code but no success: request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };  I'm still trying to figure out what this error exactly means.

Comment: I think the offending json property is "u_first_assigned_to"   the two possible values it will return are:   "u_first_assigned_to":{"link":"somevaluehere","value":"990947696f63210000ca5d02be3ee408"}    OR   "u_first_assigned_to":""   How would I go about creating a class for this so that it will accept these two types of values?

Comment: Looks like I resolved my issue.  public string u_first_assigned_to { get; set; }  should be public object u_first_assigned_to { get; set; }